# How to get list of items and all items that connected to it in one query

Tags: sql, database

Exist two tables STUDEN, FRIEND

STUDENT with ID, NAME

and

FRIEND ID_1, ID_2

I want to get list of student with their friend by one query?

some thing like

```
select * from student join friend on student.id = id_1 where ????
```

I don't know how to implement the where clause?
and what the performance issue?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current SQL attempt. (Note that you won't learn much if we do your homework for you!)

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a list of students with their friends using a single query, you can use a JOIN operation. However, since the friend relationship is stored in the `FRIEND` table with two ID columns (`ID_1` and `ID_2`), you'll need to join the `STUDENT` table twice to get both the student and their friend's information.

Here's an example query that retrieves the list of students with their friend's information:

```sql
SELECT s.ID AS StudentID, s.NAME AS StudentName, f.ID_2 AS FriendID, fs.NAME AS FriendName
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN FRIEND f ON s.ID = f.ID_1
JOIN STUDENT fs ON f.ID_2 = fs.ID;
```

In this query:

1. We select the `ID` and `NAME` columns from the `STUDENT` table as `StudentID` and `StudentName`, respectively.
2. We select the `ID_2` column from the `FRIEND` table as `FriendID`.
3. We join the `STUDENT` table with the `FRIEND` table using the condition `s.ID = f.ID_1`.
4. We join the result from the previous join with the `STUDENT` table again using the condition `f.ID_2 = fs.ID`.
5. Finally, we select the `NAME` column from the second join as `FriendName`.

The result of this query will provide you with a list of students along with their friend's ID and name.

Regarding performance, the query should perform reasonably well if you have proper indexes defined on the relevant columns (`ID`, `ID_1`, and `ID_2`). Make sure to create indexes on these columns to enhance query performance, especially if the tables contain a large number of rows. Additionally, ensure that the database server is properly tuned and has sufficient resources to handle the query load efficiently.

Comment: Seems you copied the SQL literally from Xafivy's answer.

Comment: @trincot ROFL (not at you, but at the irony) - The reason it looks like one answer was copied from the other is that (it appears to me) *both* answers were copied from ChatGPT.